# QSvgRenderer - correct rendering of svg-items despite of defaultSize()?

Tags: c++, qt, svg

That is how i try to render SVG:

```
void DialogImageProperies::showSVG(QString sFile){
    this->adjustSize();

    QSvgRenderer rndr(sFile);   
    QPixmap px;
    QSizeF szSvgF = rndr.defaultSize();

    if (szSvgF.width() > szSvgF.height())
    {
        px = QPixmap(1000, int(qreal(1000 )* szSvgF.height()/szSvgF.width()));
    }
    else
    {
        px = QPixmap(int(qreal(1000 )* szSvgF.width()/szSvgF.height()), 1000 );
    }


    QPainter p(&px);
    rndr.render(&p);

    ui->wdgBck->setPixmap(px);
    this->exec();
}
```

But as for me, i never notice what is a size of canvas in any created by myself vector-image. So, i think that users also will not predefine correct boundaries.

That is how SVG looks in Inkscape - [Inkscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O0hQ.jpg)
That is what i get - [rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30xF1.jpg)

For now i see no way to workaround all it...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="hhhhhhhhhhh_slide2.svg"
   **width="1250"**
   **height="961.25"**>
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
.......
......
```

If manually delete **width="1250"** and **height="961.25"** then Qt recalculate real itemsBoundingRect of svg)))